# Oracle PL-SQL function getting error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

```
create or replace function noMembers(projNum integer) return integer IS
memCount integer;
Begin
    memCount := ( select count(*)
                from TABLE( select p.members from Projects p where p.projNo = projNum));
    return memCount;
End;
End;
```

When I try to create the above function in Oracle - SQL*Plus, I get the errors;

```
    LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/10     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of
         the following:
         ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
         continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
         sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
         date <a string literal with character set specification>
         <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
         <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set
         specification>
         <an alternat
    LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------

4/69     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the
         following:
         , ; for <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> as group having
         intersect minus order start union where connect
```

Can't seem to find what is wrong with the function declaration, where I want to return the number of members (member count) assigned to each project from the function.

```
select count(*) from TABLE( select p.members from Projects p where p.projNo = 10 )
```

Above query when executed alone works perfectly fine. Also I need the '`memCount`' variable declared in the function.
Appreciate any help ...

Comment: `select count(*) into memcount from ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign the result of a query like that; the syntax is:

```
select count(*)
into memCount 
from ...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=56364c1fd29a73e94a7b505d21315b26)

The syntax [is in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/SELECT-INTO-statement.html)

---

> But is it possible to assign to the memCount variable by any chance ( I mean using ' := ' operator ) ?

[Not directly from a query](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-356CB656-68ED-4869-8C67-FE93A78AEC9A). You could query the whole collection into a local variable, and you could then assign the count of that:

```
create or replace function noMembers(projNum integer) return integer IS
    memCount integer;
    memColl projects.members%type;
Begin
    select p.members
    into memColl
    from Projects p where p.projNo = projNum;

    memCount := memColl.count;
    return memCount;
End;
/
```

or without the assignment:

```
create or replace function noMembers(projNum integer) return integer IS
    memColl projects.members%type;
Begin
    select p.members
    into memColl
    from Projects p where p.projNo = projNum;

    return memColl.count;
End;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ed9c57aa0ff309e67c8a3d5aaa9f5c58)

but unless you plan to do anything else with the collection that's probably just a waste of effort and memory.

Comment: Thank you for the answer...! It works great. But is it possible to assign to the memCount variable by any chance ( I mean using ' := ' operator ) ?

Comment: Why are you fixated on using an assignment operator.  The construct of "SELECT .. INTO'  _is_ how the result of a query is assigned to a variable, using PL/SQL.